# Accessing elements using selenium

Tags: java, selenium

Please help me regarding how to access "File upload"(google drive) using selenium

[image]

After login to google drive, on click of "new" is populating a pop-up contains options "Folder", "File upload", "Folder upload"etc.,

My question is: How to access "File upload" (there is no option of inspecting that element in browser).

Thanks

Comment: you can use sikuli in selenium . to locate that element

Answer (score 1):

If you want to upload files much better to use https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads.

Xpath for the button is:

```
.//div[.='File upload']
```

HTML:

```
<div class="h-v" role="menuitem" id=":2q" style="user-select: none;">
    <div class="h-v-x">
      <span class="h-v-c a-v-c a-v-c-mh">
        <div>
          <svg class="a-s-fa-Ha-pa" x="0px" y="0px" width="20px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 20 20" focusable="false" fill="#000000">
            <path d=""></path>
          </svg>
        </div>
      </span>
      <span class="a-v-j">
        <span class="a-v-ff">
          <div class="a-v-T">File upload</div>
        </span>
      </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code probably will be:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[aria-label='New']")).click();
new WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//div[.='File upload']"))).click();
```